# How to generate a topic from a list of titles using LDA (Python)?

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, gensim, lda

I am new to natural language processing.
I have a list of blog titles, for example (Not real data, but you get the point):

```
docs = ["Places to Eat", "Places to Visit", "Top 10 Things to Do in Singapore"]...
```

There are about 3000 over titles and I want to use LDA in Python to generate topics for each of this title. Assuming that I have already cleaned and tokenised these texts using nltk package and removed the stopwords, I will end up with:

```
texts = [["places","eat"],["places","visit"]]...
```

I then proceed to convert these texts into Bag-of-words:

```
from gensim import corpora, models
dictionary = corpora.Dictionary(texts)

corpus = [dictionary.doc2bow(text) for text in texts]
```

Corpus data looks like this:

```
[(0, 1), (1, 1)]...
```

Model creation:

```
import gensim
ldamodel = gensim.models.ldamodel.LdaModel(corpus, num_topics=30, id2word = dictionary, passes=20)
```

How do I make use of this model to generate a list of topics - For example "Eat", "Visit", etc. for each of this titles? I understand that the output might contain probabilities but I would like to string them together with only the text.

Comment: This is a broad topic - you'll have better luck reading a few academic papers, and looking at implementations that others have posted to GitHub or similar places.

Comment: Go through this blog: https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2017/01/sentiment-analysis-of-twitter-posts-on-chennai-floods-using-python/

Comment: See https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/tutorial.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can retrieve a list of document topics from a gensim LDA with

```
Ldamodel.show_topics()
```

and then classify a new document with

```
Ldamodel.get_document_topics(doc)
```

where doc is a document bag-of-words vector.

https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/ldamodel.html